# git: how to merge commits from a remote to a different path?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have a git repository with remote foo.

foo is a web app, is contains some files and dirs directly in its root:

```
Rakefile
app
...
public
script
```

My main git repository is a larger system which comprises this web app. I want to pull the commits from foo, but I need the files to reside inside the `web` dir. So they should become `web/app`, `web/public`, etc.

I don't want to use foo as a submodule. I want to merge foo into the main repository and then get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a community-wiki version of your answer if you'd like to accept it as the answer.

---

This answers my question:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html

Answer (score 4):

This answers my question:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html

Answer (score 2):

The up-to-date resources for **subtree merging** are:

- [Git Book chapter 7.8](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_subtree_merge)
- [How to use the subtree merge strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html)
- GitHub article "[Working with subtree merge](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge)"

Cite from [How to use the subtree merge strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html):

> In this example, let’s say you have the repository at `/path/to/B` (but it can be an URL as well, if you want).
> You want to merge the master branch of that repository to the `dir-B` subdirectory in your current branch.

> Here is the command sequence you need:

```
$ git remote add -f Bproject /path/to/B
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit Bproject/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=dir-B/ -u Bproject/master
$ git commit -m "Merge B project as our subdirectory"

$ git pull -s subtree Bproject master
```

See also for comments the article "[Subtree merging and you](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/subtree-merging-and-you/)".